# Flex - how to display tooltips when using a DataGridColumn itemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder, itemrenderer

On my flex (flash builder 4) DataGrid - DataGridColumn , I have set  a custom itemRenderer

```
itemRenderer="myComponents.EncounterDGItemRenderer".
```

My renderer is a Label

```
public class EncounterDGItemRenderer extends Label
```

I found that my tooltips (datatips) stopped working once I started using this custom renderer.  I also found that I can set the tooltip on the label in the

```
override protected function updateDisplayList
```

by setting:

```
toolTip=data['addedDate'];
```

This works find, however the problem is I need to choose a different data field based on the column.   I was hoping for something similar to how a DataGridColumn labelFunction works - where I have access to "column.headerText" or "column.dataField".  However I only have access to the underlying data object, not the name of what is being displayed (unless I am missing something).

Is there a way in a data grid item renderer to know what the column header text is, or do you have a different approach?

Comment: Are you using Flex 4?  Why not use the Spark DataGrid?

Comment: I am using a custom component (ResuableFx) DataGrid library, it has filtering and custom search capabilities.    It works great and I am using a custom item renderer so I can change the text / background color, but then I loose my tooltips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with an answer that seems to work - I used a custom item renderer extending DataGridItemRenderer instead of extending 'Label'.   Then, I set background = true and backgroundColor in there based on 'data' like I did above.

Then, the normal mxml show data tips / data tip field properties in the data grid columns work fine.

It makes sense though, this component should probably be upgraded to use Spark datagrid components - I am guessing that will allow background color and tool tips.